# jSoup get data from webpage and display in JavaFX TableView

Tags: java, javafx, jsoup, observablelist

I would like to get the Date, Distance and Fin columns from this webpage: http://www.gbgb.org.uk/raceCard.aspx?dogName=Ballymac%20Monleek and display that data in a TableView in JavaFX.

How would I go about selected the specified columns using jSoup, and then put those columns into a TableView?

My current code is only able to grab the "Fin" columns from that webpage - I'm finding it difficult to work out how to get the other two columns, and then I'm not sure how to put them in an Observable List to display in Table View.

```
    Dog dog = (Dog)tblRunners.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    String selectedDog = dog.getName();

    //getHistory
    String dogPage = "http://www.gbgb.org.uk/raceCard.aspx?dogName=" + selectedDog;
    Document doc1 = Jsoup.connect(dogPage).get();

    Element tblHeader = doc1.select("tbody").first();
    for (Element element1 : tblHeader.children()){
        String position = element1.select("td:eq(4)").text();
        System.out.println("Position: " + position);

}
```

Thanks
Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I would use a POJO for the data in the page, for Example:

```
public class DogDetail {

    private String date;
    private String distance;
    private String fin;

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    public String getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }
    public void setDistance(String distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }
    public String getFin() {
        return fin;
    }
    public void setFin(String fin) {
        this.fin = fin;
    }
}
```

2. I would use another selecting path at tblHeader variable and use the `FXCollections.observableArrayList` function to have an observable list. The code:

```
Element tblHeader = doc1.select("table.MasterTable_Web20 tbody").first();
List<DogDetail> data = new ArrayList<>();
for (Element element1 : tblHeader.children()){
    DogDetail dogDetail = new DogDetail();
    dogDetail.setDate(element1.select("td:eq(0)").text());
    dogDetail.setDistance(element1.select("td:eq(1)").text());
    dogDetail.setFin(element1.select("td:eq(4)").text());
    data.add(dogDetail);
}

TableView<DogDetail> table = new TableView<DogDetail>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(data));
```